# Retrieving two columns from one table inserting into another table using mySQL and PHP

Tags: sql, arrays, merge, insert, implode

I have two tables in mySQL, notably accounts and subscriber_data.

I want to use two columns present in the accounts table (id, name), and insert it to the subscriber_data table in two columns called (sub_id, value).

I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve this information and put it into the other table without it being bunched up in the same value field in the same row like this: 0, 0, 1

Currently, my PHP looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($alt_result = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
$id[] = $alt_result[0];
$value1[] = $alt_result[1];
}
$idstring = implode(', ', $id); 
$value1 = implode(', ', $value1); 


$sql = "INSERT INTO subscriber_data (field_id, sub_id, value) VALUES('1', '$idstring', '$value1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='$value1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I am a novice at this, and obviously doing something wrong... I searched and couldn't find an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT id, name FROM accounts` instead of `SELECT * FROM accounts`?

Comment: Yeah I have.  But I'm not sure how to use that result afterwards to insert it into the new database...

Comment: Would I be doing @Andriy M:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subscriber_data (field_id, sub_id, value) VALUES('1', '$result') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='$value1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see at first what you were doing in PHP before calling the insert script. Maybe because I'm not used to PHP scripting, though more probably because I didn't pay enough attention at the time.

So, as far as I can understand what you are doing, you seem to be doing it wrong way.

If you need to insert values from one table into another table, you just use the `INSERT...SELECT` construct.

In your case it should possibly be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO subscriber_data (field_id, sub_id, value)
SELECT '1', id, name
FROM accounts
```

Note that this is one instruction, and it replaces both `SELECT...` and `INSERT...` in your code. I think it will be enough if you leave only the last two lines of your PHP script above, where the SQL script you are storing to `$sql` should simply be modified according to my suggestion.

If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I was trying to over complicate things.